# Rstudio - how to export and share your own library

Tags: r, package, export, rstudio

I developed my own library in RStudio - how would I share it with coworkers? Is there a export package function that I can export and email / deposit to share drive - the complete source or binary package? And then how to import it?

Thanks,

Comment: (1) I think you mean package, not library, (2) many people accomplish this via GitHub, BitBucket, etc. their version control repository of choice. You can install packages from those places using **devtools**.

Comment: Even if you don't use one of the version control repos that @joran suggested, you can still create packages manually. `devtools` is a great tool for simplifying it, but it's just preference. Lots of tutorials exist, including [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/), [R package primer](http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/), and the quintessential gospel for all, [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html). Once created, the `.tar.gz` package source can be installed directly and manually (though deps are not necessarily enforced) with `install.packages)`.

Comment: If you're used to RStudio w/o using devtools, then you could just use the the Build Source Package or Build Binary Package options from the gear button popup on the Build tab. That will create something you can give to co-workers to install.

Comment: Sure - I will read the references above - what I did already is build Source Package - and then reference that package as  library from the rest of the code; How do I share that with coworkers - just zip the package directory?

Comment: The result of either "Build" I mentioned will be compressed archive file that you can share with folks.

Comment: I see it - thank you!

Comment: Tar file worked - imported from the other code/installed as package from tar file. Thank you.